# "Nested" probabilities explanation

Tags: probability, information-theory

In probing that the entropy $H(p)$ is a concave function one [usually](http://madhu.seas.harvard.edu/MIT/ST06/scribe/L03_dskim116_main.pdf) construct three probability densities as follows:

> Let $X_1$ be a random variable with distribution $p_1$, taking values in the set $A$. Let $X_2$ be another random variable with distribution $p_2$ on the same set. Let $\theta=1$ with probability $\alpha$ and $\theta=2$ with probability $1-\alpha$. Let $Z=X_\theta$. Then the distribution of $Z$ is $\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2$. Since $H(Z)\geq H(Z|\theta)$ the concavity of $H$ follows easiliy.

My stupid question is how to understand this construction of probabilities. Specially what does it mean $Z=X_\theta$, and why for instance $H(Z|\theta)=\lambda H(p_1)+(1-\lambda)H(p_2)$ and not (!) $H(Z|\theta)=\lambda H((\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2)/\lambda)+(1-\lambda)H((\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2)/(1-\lambda))$?

(Part of the answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789636/subscript-notation-for-combining-random-variables-cover-proof-of-theorem-2-7-3) but I still think that one can explain more intuitively what is $Z$.)

Answer (score 1):

> what does it mean $Z=X_\theta$

It's a (not very standard) notation for a *mixture*, that is random variable that is defined as

$$Z=\begin{cases}X_1 & \text{if } \theta = 1\\
X_2 & \text{if } \theta = 2
\end{cases}$$

Then $p(Z|\theta = 1) =p(X_1)$ and $H(Z | \theta = 1) = H(X_1)$ and then, by definition of conditional entropy

$$H(Z | \theta) =  p(\theta=1) H(Z | \theta = 1)  + p(\theta=2) H(Z | \theta = 2)= \alpha H(X_1) + (1-\alpha) H(X_2)$$